# Wordpress multisites same table users

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress multisites and I want the users in all sites be the same 
and I can't figure it out.

I did try 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables

```
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix.'my_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix.'my_usermeta' );
```

didn't work!

Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by "multisites"? Have you installed more than one? Where is that `$table_prefix being defined?

Comment: i mean wordpress network

Comment: You mean ***one***? What about `prefix`??